# using BeautifulSoup to grab data from a table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've read through countless other posts and tried a lot of techniques, but I can't seem to get the data I want from a table on the below website. I can only return other divs and their classes, but not the values.

I am looking to get all the rows from the three columns (by airline, by origin airport, by destination airport) here:
https://flightaware.com/live/cancelled

I've tried searching for the 'th class' but it only returns the div information and not the data.

Any help is appreciated

Thank you

my attempt:

```
rows = soup.findAll('table', attrs={'class': 'cancellation_boards'})
for r in rows:
    t = r.find_all_next('div', attrs= {'class':'cancellation_board'})
for r in rows:
    r.text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you see is loaded via Ajax request so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. You can simulate it via `requests`. To load the data to one big dataframe, you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = "https://flightaware.com/ajax/airport/cancelled_count.rvt"

params = {
    "type": "airline",
    "timeFilter": "((b.sch_block_out BETWEEN '2022-04-02 8:00' AND '2022-04-03 8:00') OR (b.sch_block_out IS NULL AND b.filed_departuretime BETWEEN '2022-04-02 8:00' AND '2022-04-03 8:00'))",
    "timePeriod": "today",
    "airportFilter": "",
}

all_dfs = []
for params["type"] in ("airline", "destination", "origin"):
    df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url, params=params).text)[0]
    df["type"] = params["type"]
    all_dfs.append(df)

df_final = pd.concat(all_dfs)
print(df_final)
df_final.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
                              Airline                                                   Airport Cancelled      Delayed              type
                              Airline                                                   Airport         #    %       #    %             
0                       China Eastern                                                       NaN       509  45%      28   2%      airline
1                     Spring Airlines                                                       NaN       443  82%       5   0%      airline
2                           Southwest                                                       NaN       428  12%    1369  39%      airline
3                   American Airlines                                                       NaN       317  10%     472  16%      airline
4                               Delta                                                       NaN       229   8%     444  16%      airline
5                              Spirit                                                       NaN       190  23%     207  26%      airline
6                     Hainan Airlines                                                       NaN       167  41%       9   2%      airline
7                             JetBlue                                                       NaN       144  14%     494  48%      airline
8                            Lion Air                                                       NaN       129  20%      53   8%      airline
9                             easyJet                                                       NaN       121   8%     471  32%      airline

...
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the csv file, I noticed weird characters (How can I fix such a problem of uni-coding?)

Comment: @YasserKhalil Try to set `encoding="utf-8"` parameter in `.to_csv()` (but it should be set as default). If you open it in Excel, try to set also UTF-8 as input encoding.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have to add -sig too like that `df_final.to_csv('data.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)`

Answer (score 2):

As the url is dynamic, you also can grab table data `pandas with selenium`.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

url ="https://flightaware.com/live/cancelled"
    
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)


soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
table=soup.select_one('table.cancellation_boards')
#driver.close()

df = pd.read_html(str(table),header=0)[0]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
 By airline Unnamed: 1 By origin airport Unnamed: 3         By destination airport
0    Cancelled  Cancelled           Delayed    Delayed                        Airline
1            #          %                 #          %                        Airline
2    Cancelled  Cancelled           Delayed    Delayed                        Airport
3            #          %                 #          %                        Airport
4    Cancelled  Cancelled           Delayed    Delayed                        Airport
..         ...        ...               ...        ...                            ...
308         10         3%                55        17%    Luis Munoz Marin Intl (SJU)
309         10         3%               126        39%    Geneva Cointrin Int'l (GVA)
310          9         2%                33        10%                   Sydney (SYD)
311          9        11%                17        21%              Punta Gorda (PGD)
312          9         3%                10         3%  Chengdu Shuangliu Int'l (CTU)     

[313 rows x 5 columns]
```